# WAL History reservation concept explained

Tags: ignite, wal

Could anyone explain me concept of wal history reservation [ignite under the hood](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/%28Partition+Map%29+Exchange+-+under+the+hood#id-(PartitionMap)Exchange-underthehood-Phase1.Accumulationofpartitionstate) ?
We have a cluster with 6 data nodes, native persistence enabled. Wal archiving disabled for performance reasons.

We had a crash of first node (NODE_SEGMENTED, gc pause or tcp connection problems). Second data node after that crash started to supply first node. So, second stopped to rotate Wal logs. First (segmented) node didnt work long period of time, and wal logs on second node consumed all free space. (And second node finally failed too).

How to stop wal logs growing? Why ignite uses wal logs to partition exchange, not real data from memory or persistence store?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should refer to "under the hood" articles since they are useful to database engine developers, not to database users.

Normally, some entries from WAL archive can be deleted after checkpoint passes.

You can try decreasing WAL archive size. This is described on [WAL Archive documentation page](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/write-ahead-log#section-wal-archive).

*UPD*: After some discussion it seems that WAL may also be used for historical rebalancing so it makes sense to keep some extra WAL. So you should really configure your WAL archive allowance to suit available storage. It is also advised to keep WAL archive on different drive (slower but larger is okay).

Comment: I think all professional database users should understand database internals. Black box development is not my choice.